# What does mean 'default_' part of a template view in a component?

Tags: php, templates, joomla, components

I have noticed that a name of a template in joomla's component view begins with "default_" part. What the reason for it, how it can be changed?

Comment: This is done for sub templates. I dont see why you would need to change this as it has no effect and would require editing component files which unless are template overrides, should not be done.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, but you may have not understood me correctly (english is not my mother tongue) by "change" i meant how to use it, for example, com_content has view category and templates such as default_articles and blog_item, how to use tmpl such as the last?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply create different template overrides as you like. F.ex. in com_content article view, make a copy of default.php and call it simple.php. You can display the new article template by calling index.php?option=com_content&view=article&tmpl=simple&id=an-id.

The _ - notation is to be able to divide the template into logical parts. F.ex. for the category blog-layout you have blog.php as the entry-point. The blog-layout is looping throug the content items in the category, and calling blog_item.php for each article item. So code relating directly to each article is handled here. If you override files in the template, you can choose to only override one of the files( like blog_item.php ), and let the other file get handled by by the component as usual.

regards Jonas